# Set IDs of controls of a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that contains a few controls and I want to set their ID's based on the IDs from database.
The datasource of the repeater is a list so basicly I want to do something like this in code behind, in repeater_ItemDataBound():

```
var myControl = e.Item.FindControl("controlID");
myControl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
myControl.ID = e.Item.DataItem("ID"); //but I can't access the ID property, so here's my problem.
```

considering that I declared my repeater something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="someClass">
               <asp:Label ID="controlID"  runat="server"><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:Label>
               <!-- list of other controls -->
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change ID's of controls that were already created with a different ID. That could cause nasty errors. Instead use the right ID in the first place. Or use whatever ID you use and assign the identifier  to a different property like `CommandArgument` if it's a `Button`, `Value` if it's a `HiddenField` or `Text` if it's an (invisible) `TextBox` or `Label`.

So in this case you could use another control to store the ID:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID")%>' />
<asp:Label ID="lblName"  runat="server"><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:Label>
```

Now, if you need the ID of the current item and you have the reference of the label or another control in that repeater-item:

```
var item = (RepeaterItem) lblName.NamingContainer;
HiddenField hiddenID = (HiddenField) item.FindControl("hiddenID");
string id = hiddenID.Value;
```

Comment: I see, thanks. The reason I need the ID is because I want to be able to delete the clicked item from DB. So if I set the CommandArgument (property i didn't knew till now) of a button to the item's ID in DB and on click event I delete that item is a good practice?

Comment: @next_user: yes it is. You could also use the `HiddenField` as shown above to store the ID and get it in the button-click event handler via `var btn = (Button)sender; var item=(RepeaterItem) btn.NamingContainer; var hiddenID = (HiddenField) item.FindControl("hiddenID");`.